# How to select each drop-down column by itself using one function

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a drop-down bar with few columns. I wrote a function but it works only for the first column. I tried already by className . How could I open them one by one? Now if I click the 3rd one for example it opens the first one 
Here is the live https://codepen.io/oleanderek/pen/dwEZxN

```js
var expanded = false;
function showCheckboxes() {
 var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
 if (!expanded) {
  checkboxes.style.display = "block";
  expanded = true;
 } else {
  checkboxes.style.display = "none";
  expanded = false;
 }
}

function changeArrow() {
 var arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");

 if (arrow.classList.contains("down-arrow")) {
  // Has my-class in it
  arrow.classList.remove("down-arrow");
  arrow.classList.add("up-arrow");
 }

 else if (arrow.classList.contains("up-arrow")) {
  // Has my-class in it
  arrow.classList.remove("up-arrow");
  arrow.classList.add("down-arrow");
 }
}
```

```css
.github {
  margin-top: 50px; }

.multiselect {
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 40;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; }

.selectBox {
  position: relative; }

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold; }

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0; }

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border: none; }

.checkboxes__container {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px; }

.checkboxes__container--input {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 15px; }

.checkboxes__container--text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 15px; }

#checkboxes input {
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff; }

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid lightgray; }

#checkboxes label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 13px;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #6d3838;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg); }

#checkboxes label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0; }

#checkboxes input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden; }

#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1; }

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 170px !important;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 25px; }

.select-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5; }

.down-arrow {
background-image:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cursor.png");}

.up-arrow {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/change_password.png"); }

#arrow {
  width: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #00a671; }

.squaredFour {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto; }

.squaredFour label {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid lightgray; }

.squaredFour label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 25%;
  /* transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
  border: 2px solid #6d3838;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg); }

.squaredFour label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0; }

.squaredFour input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden; }

.squaredFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="multiselect">
    <div>
     <div  class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes(); changeArrow();">
      <div class="select-container">
       <select>
        <option>ogródek/strych</option>
       </select>
       <img id="arrow" class="down-arrow" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="overSelect"></div>
     </div>

     <div id="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
       <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="one">
        <label for="one"></label>
       </span>
       <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
        <span>ogródek</span>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
       <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="two">
        <label for="two"></label>
       </span>
       <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
        <span>strych</span>
       </span>
      </div>

     </div> 
    </div>
    <div>
     <div  class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes(); changeArrow();">
      <div class="select-container">
       <select>
        <option>status</option>
       </select>
       <img id="arrow" class="down-arrow" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="overSelect"></div>
     </div>

     <div id="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
       <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three">
        <label for="three"></label>
       </span>
       <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
        <span>wolne</span>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
       <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="four">
        <label for="four"></label>
       </span>
       <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
        <span>rezerwacja</span>
       </span>
      </div>

     </div> 
    </div>
        <div>
     <div  class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes(); changeArrow();">
      <div class="select-container">
       <select>
        <option>status</option>
       </select>
       <img id="arrow" class="down-arrow" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="overSelect"></div>
     </div>

     <div id="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
       <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="three">
        <label for="three"></label>
       </span>
       <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
        <span>wolne</span>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
       <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="four">
        <label for="four"></label>
       </span>
       <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
        <span>rezerwacja</span>
       </span>
      </div>

     </div> 
    </div>
    
   </div>
```

Comment: I cannot even click it after changing to this

Comment: Yes removed my comment, you had more issues. See my answer.

Comment: If any of the answers helped you should mark it as the answer. This will help other users

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by changing the id `checkbox` to class (id's need to be unique). When binding the click event with javascript you get nice use of `this`. You can use the property `this.nextElementSibling` property to get the `.checkbox` belonging to the arrow.

Also changed your if statement to check on the display property of the element instead of a global `var`. You do need to set the initial value on `none` to avoid bugs (it's not exactly the same as the css style)

Also you might want to combine the 2 functions depending on other usages of them.

***Note:*** You should change the elements with id `arrow` too so that i will be unique. It didn't give problems with this snippet but will likely give you headaches in the future.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".selectBox").forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', showCheckboxes);
  el.addEventListener('click', changeArrow);
  el.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
});


function showCheckboxes() {
  var thisCheckbox = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (thisCheckbox.style.display == "none") {
    thisCheckbox.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    thisCheckbox.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function changeArrow() {
  var arrow = this.getElementsByClassName('arrow')[0];
  
  if (arrow.classList.contains("down-arrow")) {
    arrow.classList.remove("down-arrow");
    arrow.classList.add("up-arrow");
  } else if (arrow.classList.contains("up-arrow")) {
    arrow.classList.remove("up-arrow");
    arrow.classList.add("down-arrow");
  }
}
```

```css
.github {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.multiselect {
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 40;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.checkboxes {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border: none;
}

.checkboxes__container {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkboxes__container--input {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.checkboxes__container--text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.checkboxes input {
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.checkboxes label {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.checkboxes label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 13px;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #6d3838;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checkboxes label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkboxes input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 170px !important;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.select-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.down-arrow {
  background-image: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cursor.png");
}

.up-arrow {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/change_password.png");
}

.arrow {
  width: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #00a671;
}

.squaredFour {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.squaredFour label {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.squaredFour label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 25%;
  /* transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
  border: 2px solid #6d3838;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredFour label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.squaredFour input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.squaredFour input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiselect">
  <div>
    <div class="selectBox">
      <div class="select-container">
        <select>
          <option>ogródek/strych</option>
        </select>
        <img class="arrow down-arrow" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
     <input type="checkbox" id="one">
     <label for="one"></label>
    </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
     <span>ogródek</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
     <input type="checkbox" id="two">
     <label for="two"></label>
    </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
     <span>strych</span>
        </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="selectBox">
      <div class="select-container">
        <select>
          <option>status</option>
        </select>
        <img class="arrow down-arrow" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
     <input type="checkbox" id="three">
     <label for="three"></label>
    </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
     <span>wolne</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
     <input type="checkbox" id="four">
     <label for="four"></label>
    </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
     <span>rezerwacja</span>
        </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="selectBox">
      <div class="select-container">
        <select>
          <option>status</option>
        </select>
        <img class="arrow down-arrow" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
     <input type="checkbox" id="three">
     <label for="three"></label>
    </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
     <span>wolne</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
     <input type="checkbox" id="four">
     <label for="four"></label>
    </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
     <span>rezerwacja</span>
        </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working but now the image is not changing I dont know why

Comment: @PatrykCzekoladyn Updated the arrow to use class too instead of id and modified the selector in the function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all an `id` can only be used once on a page. So `checkboxes` and `arrow` won't work.

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

```js
let selects = document.getElementsByClassName("selectBox");

for(let select of selects)
{
  let checkbox = select.nextElementSibling;
  let arrow = select.getElementsByClassName("arrow")[0];
  
  console.log(checkbox, arrow);
  
  select.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(checkbox.classList.contains("expanded"))
    {
      checkbox.style.display = "none"; 
      checkbox.classList.remove("expanded");
      arrow.classList.remove("up-arrow");
    arrow.classList.add("down-arrow"); 
    } else {
      checkbox.style.display = "block";
      checkbox.classList.add("expanded");
      arrow.classList.remove("down-arrow");
    arrow.classList.add("up-arrow");  
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.github {
  margin-top: 50px; }

.multiselect {
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 40;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; }

.selectBox {
  position: relative; }

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold; }

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0; }

.checkboxes {
  display: none;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border: none; }

.checkboxes__container {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px; }

.checkboxes__container--input {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 15px; }

.checkboxes__container--text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 15px; }

.checkboxes input {
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff; }

.checkboxes label {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid lightgray; }

.checkboxes label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 13px;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #6d3838;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg); }

.checkboxes label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0; }

.checkboxes input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden; }

.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1; }

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 170px !important;
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 25px; }

.select-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 170px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5; }

.down-arrow {
background-image:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cursor.png");}

.up-arrow {
  background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/change_password.png"); }

.arrow {
  width: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #00a671; }

.squaredFour {
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto; }

.squaredFour label {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid lightgray; }

.squaredFour label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 25%;
  /* transform: translate(-50%,-50%); */
  border: 2px solid #6d3838;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg); }

.squaredFour label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0; }

.squaredFour input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden; }

.squaredFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="multiselect">
  <div>
    <div  class="selectBox">
      <div class="select-container">
        <select>
          <option>ogródek/strych</option>
        </select>
        <img class="arrow down-arrow" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
          <input type="checkbox" id="one">
          <label for="one"></label>
        </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
          <span>ogródek</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
          <input type="checkbox" id="two">
          <label for="two"></label>
        </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
          <span>strych</span>
        </span>
      </div>

    </div> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <div  class="selectBox">
      <div class="select-container">
        <select>
          <option>status</option>
        </select>
        <img class="arrow down-arrow" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
          <input type="checkbox" id="three">
          <label for="three"></label>
        </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
          <span>wolne</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
          <input type="checkbox" id="four">
          <label for="four"></label>
        </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
          <span>rezerwacja</span>
        </span>
      </div>

    </div> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="selectBox">
      <div class="select-container">
        <select>
          <option>status</option>
        </select>
        <img class="arrow down-arrow" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkboxes">
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
          <input type="checkbox" id="three">
          <label for="three"></label>
        </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
          <span>wolne</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes__container">
        <span class="checkboxes__container--input">
          <input type="checkbox" id="four">
          <label for="four"></label>
        </span>
        <span class="checkboxes__container--text">
          <span>rezerwacja</span>
        </span>
      </div>

    </div> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can't close it now

Comment: @PatrykCzekoladyn please check again

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because all the checkboxes have the same id "checkboxes", so when you are trying to select by id "checkboxes" the first occurence of the html element having id: "checkboxes" is selected. 
I have solved it here: https://codepen.io/snehansh/pen/PXvawv

I have resolved your issue, by assigning the checkboxes with same class name

```
<div class="checkboxes">
```

and then I am setting a javascript variable based on the column checkbox selected,

```
<div  class="selectBox" onclick="sectionOneClicked(); showCheckboxes(); changeArrow();">

var section = null;
function sectionOneClicked() {
  section = 0;
}
```

and then inside of your function 'showCheckboxes()' I am passing the selected index to the 'checkboxes[]' array

```
function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxes");
    if (!expanded) {
        checkboxes[section].style.display = "block";
        expanded = true;
    } else {
        checkboxes[section].style.display = "none";
        expanded = false;
    }
}
```